# Changing a Type to a Class causes ByRef parameters to act ByVal

Tags: vba, class, pass-by-reference, user-defined-types

I've heard advice to change from User Defined Type (UDT) to a regular Class in order to overcome the limitations of UDT, such as not being able to use For Each with a UDT.

I've also heard advice to change from a regular Class to UDT to overcome the Class limitation where you can't pass things BYREF, like...

```
'Function:
Public Function RemoveArticle (ByRef strMovieTitle As String)
    'Expected input is like "Terminator, The"
    strMovieTitle = Left(... 'removes the article.
End Function
```

That works fine for this call:

```
Dim strMovieTitle As String
strMovieTitle = "Terminator, The"
RemoveArticle strMovieTitle
```

But not this call:

```
Dim objMovie As MovieClass
objMovie.strMovieTitle = "Terminator, The"
objMovie.strMovieGenre = "Sci-Fi"
InvertArticle objMovie.strMovieTitle
```

Even though MovieClass defines

```
strMovieTitle As String
```

I can't go changing RemoveArticle (and every simple little function like it) to take a MovieClass parameter instead of a String parameter because there are other UDTs or Classes and String Variables that also need to use RemoveArticle.

What do I do if I need to use For Each and I also need to pass ByRef?
Is there a way a Class can work around the parameter problem?

(Using Excel 2010.)

Comment: When you pass an object's property to a method (and the value of that property isn't an object itself) you're just passing a copy of the value, not the property itself, and I'm not sure there's an easy way around that. `objMovie.strMovieTitle = RemoveArticle(objMovie.strMovieTitle)` is probably the best you can do.

Comment: You may want to consider moving `InvertArticle` and `RemoveArticle` inside of the `MovieClass`.   Encapsulation all the relevant functionally inside of the class make it really easy to review and debug  (especially if you haven't worked with the code in a while) and `objMovie.RemoveArticle` is really clean.

Comment: @npeirce: you can use `Dictionary` or `Collection` where you store your `MovieClass` objects. There you can either use a `UDF` or a class called, let's say, `Movies` with those functions (_invert_ and _remove_)... Also, could you provide reference about those suggestions you herd about? As far as I know, **in a class you can** define _methods_ with parameters that are passed **`ByRef`** (in fact, any object is passed `ByRef`).

Comment: @rellampec, I have a ton of functions that use strings, so I can't really change all of them. Even if I did, they would be inaccessible or weird to use with regular string variables that have nothing to do with Movies. That is, movies aren't the only things that need articles inverted or removed. Also some functions would needs access to the internal variables of more than one type/class then.

Comment: @rellampec, I agree with you that "in a class you can define methods with parameters that are passed ByRef" but I'm saying something a bit different: Outside of a class you can define functions with params that are passed ByRef, and as a caller, you can pass a class object's variable to that function, e.g., pass objMovie.strMovieTitle but any alterations made within that function will NOT be reflected in objMovie.strMovieTitle on the very next line of code after the call is executed. See comment above by Tim Williams where he says "you're just passing a copy". That's the downside of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have understood your concern.

You simply can't take that approach to meet your goal. As Tim Williams has commented in your question, your best bet would be something like this:

```
Dim objMovie As MovieClass
Dim strMovieTitle As String
strMovieTitle = "Terminator, The"
objMovie.strMovieTitle = InvertArticle(strMovieTitle)
```

However, I see that this still does not satisfy your need.

My **suggestion** is as follows:

- make your object internal, target properties `Private` and expose them with `Property Let` and `Property Get`. This way you can do the modifications you want to the properties either on *set* or on *get* (from within the class... rather than fixing things from outside the class).

**Aside note**, in regards to create a `helper class` (as someone has recommended to you):  you could join into one class all those functions you use widely, such as `RemoveArticle` or `InvertArticle`. However, it requires to create an instance object every time you want to use them and, therefore, does not combine well with the recommendation I am giving to you (if you want just to simplify code). So having them in a `Module` as you do now is fine. Just to clarify: those recommendations they gave to you are unrelated to your question here.

**Example A: on `set`**

In you class `MovieClass`, rename first all the instances of `strMovieTitle` to `pStrMovieTitle` and add this to your code:

```
Private pStrMovieTitle As String

Public Property Let strMovieTitle (strIn As String)
 pStrMovieTitle = InvertArticle(strIn)
End Property

Public Property Get strMovieTitle As String
 strMovieTitle = pStrMovieTitle
End Property
```

The usage would be something like this:

```
Dim objMovie As MovieClass
objMovie.strMovieTitle = "Terminator, The" ' the article position gets rectified on assignation
objMovie.strMovieGenre = "Sci-Fi"
'InvertArticle objMovie.strMovieTitle ' => you don't need to do this call
```

**Example B: on `get`**

To keep your original string as it comes, and do apply your `helpers` when you get the property value. That way you always preserve the original string. However, this approach will need more rework and it's only worthy in cases where you have lots of ways to use that `String` in different parts of your code.

```
Private pStrMovieTitleSource As String

Public Property Let strMovieTitle (strIn As String)
 pStrMovieTitleSource = Trim(strIn)
End Property

Public Property Get strMovieTitleSource () As String
 strMovieTitleSource = pStrMovieTitleSource
End Property

Public Property Get strMovieTitleRoot () As String
 strMovieTitleRoot = RemoveArticle(pStrMovieTitleSource)
End Property

Public Property Get strMovieTitle () As String
 strMovieTitle = InvertArticle(pStrMovieTitleSource)
End Property
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @rellampec and everyone. I can accept "You simply can't take that approach to meet your goal." :) I very much appreciate all the extra information and advice as well!